# Why nobody is revising Newton law of universal gravitation to show that the force don't instantly act on the object?

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, speed-of-light, causality

I think Sir Newton was aware of the serious flaw when he formulated the law of gravity. We all know time is an important component in doing science, but I don't remember that anyone tried to revise the equation to include time. I wonder why do we simply accept that the speed of gravitational force acting on an object is instantaneous when applying this equation which I think is a big blunder?

Comment: Einstein's theory of general relativity is pretty much about amending the Newton's gravity...

Answer (score 9):

> I don't remember anyone tried to revise the equation to include time

The revised equation is called the Einstein field equation. It predicts that the speed is c, not instantaneous.

Answer (score 3):

One has to adopt the mindset of the physicists at the end of the nineteenth century. Maxwell's equations, including the wave equation were already known.
But instead of changing the theory of classical mechanics the physicists tried to adopt Maxwell's equations into the mechanistic picture. They invented the ether and the interactions of the electromagnetic fields were tried of being explained by mechanical motion of the ether fluid.
Moreover, Newton's theory of gravity had been extremely successful. There were only very marginal problems like the deviation of Mercury's actual perihel motion and the prediction of Newton's theory, I guess, nobody took really for serious. Several planet's and planetoid's motions had been predicted correctly by Newton's theory, nobody had the reflex to modify the theory.
The picture changed after Einstein's publication of Special Relativity (SRT) in 1905. Once accepted some physicists indeed started thinking about to modify Newton's theory, because from the SRT it was clear that interaction could no longer be instantaneous.
The most famous theory of this kind is Nordstrom's theory on gravity (1912+13). Actually Nordstrom made 2 proposals: The first simply consisted of replacing the Laplacian differential operator by the d'Alembert's one (1912):

$\square \phi = 4\pi G\rho$

where $\rho$ is the mass density. However, this theory leads to equations of motion that are wrong. But Nordstrom came up soon with another proposal (1913):

$\phi\square \phi = -4\pi G T$

$T=T^\mu_\mu$ is the trace of energy-momentum tensor of matter $T_{\mu\nu}$.
In difference to the first proposal the field equation is non-linear (a feature necessary in order to take into account that the gravitational field as a source of energy should interact with itself, a feature which is not contained in the first proposal). The theory has a couple of interesting features, in particular it leads to a conformally flat metric. However, it is not able to predict the deviation of light by (typically large) masses. This effect was checked already 1919 and decided in favour of Einstein's theory of General Relativity (Nov. 1915). So from the insight that a gravitational theory has to take into account the time delay between the source and "test particle" and the development of successfully tested (at least up to now) theory of gravity accounting for this only 10 years went by and Einstein's theory was not the only proposal on the table.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the classical description of gravity it's just the "newtonian limit" in the general theory of relativity. You can revise the equation in a flat spacetime and you obtain the analogous of a classical description of electromagnetic field with Liénard-Wiechart retarded potential [Retarded Potential in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retarded_potential) If you want a formulation for spacetime that actually includes masses, that becomes enormously complicated because spacetime interacts with itself (in other words you have nonlinear equations of motion and for the same reason superposition principle ceases to hold), so this can be solved only in specific cases: empty spacetime and so Schwarzschild solution for Einstein equations or omogeneously filled Universe and so Friedmann Robertson Walker metric and so on... So don't worry, many people have asked themselves about this since centuries! Almost every idea one has in science, can be pretty sure someone else has had it... but that's part of the game in a way, that there are more ways to get to a result

Comment: I attended a colloquium given by Richard Feynman.  He told a story of a time when he discovered something new in E&M despite a literature search.  After some time he learned that it had been done decades earlier. He said, "If you ever thing you've discovered something new in E&M, think again."   I'm sure that advice is generally applicable.

Comment: @garyp You heard and saw Feynman talking in person?! Wow! I totally agree; the fact is that as human beings we all share something and for example this is the reason why some results of quantum mechanics you can find already enounced thousands of years before ("The Tao of Physics" by Fritjof Capra is very interesting and covers this topic), clearly without the logical formalism of this time, but in a way they can be even more profound than today; this has to do even with the theories of light propagation and the "substantiality" of matter and spacetime itself.

Answer (score 1):

> [user6760](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/563446/why-nobody-is-revising-newton-law-of-universal-gravitation-to-show-that-the-forc) wrote: *I don't remember that anyone tried to revise the equation to include time.*

In that case your memory doesn't seem to be very good, because it has been tried many times.

> [user6760](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/563446/why-nobody-is-revising-newton-law-of-universal-gravitation-to-show-that-the-forc) asked: *I wonder why do we simply accept that the speed of gravitational force acting on an object is instantaneous when applying this equation which I think is a big blunder?*

When you use the Newtonian framework you have to take the speed of gravity as infinite, otherwise you get the wrong results:

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retarded_position) wrote: *So long as no radiation is emitted, conservation of momentum requires that forces between objects (either electromagnetic or gravitational forces) point at objects' instantaneous and up-to-date positions, and not in the direction of their speed-of-light-delayed (retarded) positions.*

In other words:

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retarded_position) wrote: *The attraction between static charges moving with constant relative velocity is always toward the instantaneous position of the charge (in this case, the "gravitational charge" of the Sun), not the time-retarded position of the Sun. When an object is moving in orbit at a steady speed but changing velocity v, the effect on the orbit is order v²/c², and the effect preserves energy and angular momentum, so that orbits do not decay.*

Also see https://cds.cern.ch/record/401893/files/9909087.pdf